# System compare tools

Tags: untagged

To enable us to do better change management tracking on our hosting platform, I need to be able to compare our production Windows 2003/2008 virtual servers with the base image they were cloned from.

I'm looking for a tool that will allow us to compare and report differences on such things as registry settings, installed drivers, installed applications and so on. I need this to work on machines that are standalone.

I've done a fair bit of googling but nothing jumps out at me.

Does such a tool exist?

Comment: Each software use a different method in the cloned image, so if that app exists, can be from the software provider, or a third-party done by others. There's no "global" app that does what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used SysCompare with reasonable success in the past.

Comment: Was that the Full Fat or Lite version?

Comment: @Kev That is the Full version

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly meant for Virtual machines. But afaik, it does similar thing. But it is nowhere near easy. It is a enterprise grade software from Microsoft and afaik its costly. But it delivers like anything. i have seen it in action. it does integrate with AD if you like and gives a dashboard where you can view all the details of all the machines you want to monitor. it is called sccm. System Centre Configuration manager. it can make the different machines to be same, by publishing the software to all the hosts without needing to goto individual host and installing . you have a centralized place where you can manage everything. I am not sure if this what you are looking for. I am not a windows expert. So i cant comment much on this or about the other products for windows.